# X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection is closing the application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-10, x509

On a given client, when accessing the X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection function the application is closing without even going through the error handling.

This function opens a Windows dialog box for the user to select a digital certificate.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.5, and the problem happens on a machine with Windows 10 Pro, which has about 8 valid certificates.

I did a test application, to take the logs and find out exactly where the problem happens, and it is when using the X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection function.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Iniciando a aplicação para seleção de certificado");
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("new X509Store");
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

            Console.WriteLine("store.Open");
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

            // Obtém a coleção de certificados instalados
            Console.WriteLine("store.Certificates");
            X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;

            // Excluí da coleção certificados vencidos, comparando a data corrente
            Console.WriteLine("collection.Find");
            X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);

            Console.WriteLine("X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection");
            X509Certificate2Collection certificados = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Certificados Cadastrados", "Selecione seu certificado", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);

            Console.WriteLine("store.Close");
            store.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("certificados.Count");
            if (certificados.Count == 0)
            {

            }

            Console.WriteLine("certificados[0]");
            var teste = certificados[0];
            Console.WriteLine("certificados[0].Subject");
            var texto = certificados[0].Subject;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ex.Message");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finalizando");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this error?

Comment: Can you check if `X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection` works against empty collection?

Comment: against empty collection doesn't work

Comment: if use flag X509SelectionFlag.MultiSelection then works, but the application needs just one. Using X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection doesn't work, and the application terminates.

Comment: Do you mean that the application crashes when calling the method against empty collection with `SingleSelection` flag?

Comment: exactly, it seems like windows kill the application. it happens only in windows 10.

Comment: The `X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection` methid is a wrapper over `CryptUIDlgSelectCertificate` unmanaged function. And incorrect function call may terminate the application. I think, you may need to open a support ticket with Microsoft Support. I doubt anyone will help you here.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/issues/91